# HTML linked image for email signatures?

Tags: html, image, email, hyperlink, signature

Everything works fine for Microsoft Outlook, but when the .html file is inserted to Mac Outlook 2011 the image shows up but the link does not show up. Been searching on the web for a while and couldn't fine an answer. My fault or the Macs?.
Wat do?.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Link</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://issuu.com/3foxinternational/docs/gw_complete" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QmTzKiY.jpg" alt="site link" />
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing `target="_blank"` does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook is a real PITA sometimes when it comes to viewing HTML emails. The rending engine is terrible. Also, it doesn't support HTML5.

HTML emails should always be written using very old coding standards so that they are cross email client compatible. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Link</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <a href="http://issuu.com/3foxinternational/docs/gw_complete" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QmTzKiY.jpg" alt="site link" border="0" style="display:block;" />
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```